# Screen off/screen on Broadcast receiver working only once

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm developing my lockscreen. I successfully completed all the work but the main problem now in when I lock the screen my lockscreen works for the first time when I unlock it and lock it again, my lockscreen is not working.

I am not able to find the reason behind it.

My Lockscreen Service

```
 public class LockscreenService extends Service {
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;
private WindowManager windowManager;
public static final String mypreference="mypref";
public static final String name4 ="key";
int imname;
SharedPreferences sp;
ImageView img,aimg;
final ArrayList<Bitmap> beforeshuffle = new ArrayList<>(9);
final ArrayList<Bitmap> aftershuffle = new ArrayList<>(9);
ArrayList<Bitmap> smallimages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(9);
public static final String name1 ="imgkey";
GridView grid;
Bitmap bs;
Bitmap as;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
BroadcastReceiver screenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean b = sp.getBoolean(name4, false);

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) ||intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) && linearLayout == null) {
                init();


            }

    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sp = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new   IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(screenReceiver, intentFilter);
    windowManager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
    layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

}
private void init() {


    if (sp.contains(name1)) {
        imname = sp.getInt(name1, 0);

    }
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    windowManager.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
    ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.lockscreen, linearLayout);
    //   View btnClose = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);

String wp="/data/user/0/com.example.user.myapplication/app_wallparerdir/wall.jpg";
Bitmap my = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(wp);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), my);
if(imname==1)
{
linearLayout.setBackground(d);
 }
      else {
      //Drawable image =    c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name_of_image_in_drawableFolder);
  linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(imname);
     }
    img = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.bs);
    aimg = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.as);
    grid = (GridView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    Globalvariable c=new Globalvariable();
    bs=c.giveBitmap();

    String p="/data/user/0/com.example.user.myapplication/app_imageDir/profile.jpg";
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),p,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("path",p);
   String bspath="/data/user/0/com.example.user.myapplication/app_Beforeshuffle/beforeshuffle";





    bs=loadImageFromStorage(bspath);

    // Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("bitmap");

    //smallimage_Numbers is to tell how many smallimage_s the image should split

    int smallimage_Numbers = 9;

    //Getting the source image to split

    //  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source_image);
    // File imgFile = new  File("profile.jpg"

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p);
    splitImage(myBitmap, smallimage_Numbers);
    View btnClose = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img.setImageBitmap(bs);
            as=getBitmapFromView(grid);
            aimg.setImageBitmap(as);
            Bitmap a=getBitmapFromView(img);
            Bitmap b=getBitmapFromView(aimg);
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            aimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // do something when the corky3 is clicked
            if(b.sameAs(a) ){
            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CORRECT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ///Intent service = new Intent(LockscreenService.this, calculator.class);
               // startService(service);
                Intent service = new Intent(LockscreenService.this, caclservice.class);
                startService(service);
               // windowManager.removeView(linearLayout);
               // linearLayout = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("jhgeiugh","jhgfeug");
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"WRONG",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    View btnemergency = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btnemergency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("ghfgh","dgd");
            Intent service = new Intent(LockscreenService.this, PopupService.class);
            startService(service);
        //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"setted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
        });
    View btnforgot = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btnforgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("ghfgh","dgd");
            Intent service = new Intent(LockscreenService.this, Forgotpassservice.class);
            startService(service);
            //            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"setted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

My lockscreen shows a picture puzzle to solve then a calculator to type pin no to unlock device. So the calculator Service

```
 public class caclservice extends Service {
private int[] numericButtons = {R.id.btnZero, R.id.btnOne, R.id.btnTwo, R.id.btnThree, R.id.btnFour, R.id.btnFive, R.id.btnSix, R.id.btnSeven, R.id.btnEight, R.id.btnNine};
private static final String TAG = PopupService.class.getSimpleName();
WindowManager mWindowManager;
QuestionAdapter qa;
View mView; String username;
 TextView ques;
private Session session;
String question;
private TextView txtScreen;
// Represent whether the lastly pressed key is numeric or not
private boolean lastNumeric;
// Represent that current state is in error or not
private boolean stateError=false;
// If true, do not allow to add another DOT
private boolean lastDot;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  stateError=false;
   showDialog();

  super.onCreate();
}


   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    session=new Session(this);
    qa=new QuestionAdapter(this);
    username=session.getusename();
    question=qa.fetchreco(username);



    setNumericOnClickListener();
    return START_STICKY;
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void showDialog() {
   // PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   // PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "caclservice");
   // mWakeLock.acquire();
   // mWakeLock.release();

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.calculator, null);
    mView.setTag(TAG);

    int top = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2;

    LinearLayout dialog = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.lin);
   // if you want to set params
   //        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) dialog.getLayoutParams();
 //        lp.topMargin = top;
  //        lp.bottomMargin = top;
 //        mView.setLayoutParams(lp);
   txtScreen = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);
    // ques.setText(question);

    // final EditText etMassage = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.ans);
    //etMassage.setText("");
   /* ImageButton imageButtonSend = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSendInPopupMessageReceived);
  //        lp = (LayoutParams) imageButton.getLayoutParams();
  //        lp.topMargin = top - 58;
 //        imageButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
    imageButtonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(!etMassage.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {

                etMassage.setText("");
            }
        }
    });*/

    Button cancel = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
  //  close.setText("Cancel");
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            hidethisDialog();
        }
    });
    Button close = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnEqual);
    // close.setText("Cancel");
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String ans = txtScreen.getText().toString();
            if (ans.trim().equals(question.trim())) {

                stateError=true;

                hideDialog();
               // int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON;
               // getWindow().addFlags(flags);

            }
        }
    });


    final WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                //    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, mLayoutParams);

}
private void setNumericOnClickListener() {
    // Create a common OnClickListener
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Just append/set the text of clicked button
            Button button = (Button) v;
            if (stateError) {
                // If current state is Error, replace the error message
            txtScreen.setText(button.getText());
                stateError = false;
            } else {
                // If not, already there is a valid expression so append to it
              txtScreen.append(button.getText());
            }
            // Set the flag
            lastNumeric = true;
        }
    };
    // Assign the listener to all the numeric buttons
    for (int id : numericButtons) {
        mView.findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
private void hidethisDialog(){
    if(mView != null && mWindowManager != null){
        mWindowManager.removeView(mView);
        mView = null;

    }
}
private void hideDialog(){
    if(mView != null && mWindowManager != null){
        mWindowManager.removeView(mView);
        mView = null;

        startService(new Intent(this, LockscreenService.class));


/*
 * Notify the system to finalize and collect all objects of the
 * application on exit so that the process running the application can
 * be killed by the system without causing issues. NOTE: If this is set
 * to true then the process will not be killed until all of its threads
 * have closed.
 */
            System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);

/*
 * Force the system to close the application down completely instead of
 * retaining it in the background. The process that runs the application
 * will be killed. The application will be completely created as a new
 * application in a new process if the user starts the application
 * again.
 */
            System.exit(0);
       // stopService(new Intent(ActivityName.this, ServiceClassName.class));
        }
    }


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I Call this in activity to lock screen

```
Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockscreenService.class);
    getApplication().startService(service);
```

Comment: Try creating dynamic broadcast receiver out of service.

Comment: But what i found from other stackoverflkow questions page is to run Br out of app it should be declared in service

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If Broadcast Receiver not working then you can make a Service that run background continuously and watching that screen is off/on.

like this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

     if (isScreenOn) {

         //Screen is on 
     }
     else
     {
        //Screen is off
     }
```

Comment: inside your service

Comment: when i do this it comes every time when i open any app and close it

Comment: you should manage flags when screen is on and screen is off as per your logic when you want to display your lock screen

Comment: my lockscreen is working continuosly for some time like 5 minitue after registration then it is not working what might be the reason

Comment: check your service will be killed or running when screen lock not occur

Comment: how to check it

Comment: Print log continually in service if log will not displayed then service will be stoped or killed

Comment: to test lockscreen we use power button know so log is not printining VM didconnected is only coming